# which port to use for applet servlet communication

Tags: java, servlets, applet, port

I am trying to communicate between an applet and a servlet. I first tried Http connection. But I am not getting the desired result. Hence decided to switch to socket communication. Hence I wanted to know which port to use for the same. I remember reading somewhere that port 80 is ideal. Is it port 80 or port 8080? I need a port that is not blocked by firewall(default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, an Applet can only connect to the same host as the applet was served from. You can't set up TCP connections arbitrary hosts. (see e.g. [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html) for info on how to sign an applet, signed applets does not have this restriction)

Using port 80 likely will not work either, as your web server probably works on port 80. Port 80 is really the only port that you usually can count not being blocked, if your servlet container is running on port 8080 , port 80 might be free for you to use though.

imo, try rather to communicate with http so you can talk to a servlet - and work out whatever desired results you had trouble with.

Comment: I took yours and BalusC advice. I decided to fix the Http connection problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509686/help-with-chat-server The full problem statement is posted here. Any help is appreciated.